# Squid isn't caching

Tags: squid

why am I always getting TCP_MISS:DIRECT? Why isn't Squid caching?

```
66.55.138.70 - - [20/Oct/2010:14:42:58 +0000] "GET
http://alexus.org/egg.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 12001 "http://alexus.org/"
"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_4; en-US)
AppleWebKit/533.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/5.0.375.70 Safari/533.4"
TCP_MISS:DIRECT
```

Comment: Did you double check in squid's caching directories that there aren't items in there? Anything in Squid's logs? What does your config file look like?

Comment: there are bunch of directories/files in there. config is pretty much is out of the box

Answer (score 1):

When I hit that URL I get a non-cacheable response:

```
Content-Length: 1601
Date: Wed, 20 Oct 2010 16:30:49 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Etag: "1e52b84-641-42d9d29c90d40"
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Sun, 08 Apr 2007 17:22:21 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes

200 OK
```

Comment: why this url isn't cacheable? I'm using that URL as an example. according to my logs, it looks like nothing is cacheable

Comment: Have a read of http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/